# Is Netlink is the medium for Syscall events?

Tags: kernel, system-calls

When we run an application when the syscall event has got raised,will that syscall events are  passed  via net-link to kernel? or netlink is related to syscall by any chance please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever Syscall need to be triggered, user space program executes a command `int 0x80` after copying few values in register eax, ebx, ecx, edx, esi, and edi as per required by syscall.

After `int 0x80` is executed, PC jumps to ISR for that softirq.

routine for syscall is being set by `set_system_trap_gate(MY_SYSCALL_VECTOR, entry_INT80_32);` you can check it here `arch/x86/kernel/traps.c`.

and the entry point for Syscall in kernel is `entry_INT80_32`, which can be found in `arch/x86/entry/entry_32.S` and it is define by linker script `ENTRY(entry_INT80_32)` in the same file.

Through this entry point you can check, how it is copying the value of registers eax, ebx, ecx, edx, esi, and edi. Then moving to particular syscall as per syscall number, executing and returning back to user space.

Comment: Ok Thank you for your response,Is there any relevancy to netlink ?

Comment: though netlink is also used for communication between user space and kernel space, but not in case of system call. For data transfer between kernel and user space during a syscall only eax, ebx, ecx, edx, esi, and edi registers are used.

Comment: Thank you samrat:)

Comment: if it was helpful, upvote or accepted answer would be appreciated. thanks!